# boost asio error when read/write more than 100000 messages

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I received the following exception in `handleRead()` function from `boost::asio::read()` when I read and write more than 100000 of messages.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of
'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
what():  asio.ssl error
```

Implementation is below

### Read Function

```
void start()
{
boost::asio::async_read(_socket,
boost::asio::buffer(_messageHeader, 8),
    _strand.wrap(
      boost::bind(
        handleRead,
        shared_from_this(),
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
        )
      )
    );
}

void handleRead(const boost::system::error_code& e,
   std::size_t bytesTransferred)
{
  if (!e) 
  {

   BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof(MessageHeader) == 8 );

   Message message;
   message.header.fromString(
      std::string(_messageHeader.data(),
        sizeof(MessageHeader)
        )
      );

    boost::asio::read(_socket,
       boost::asio::buffer(_buffer, message.header.length));

   message.body = std::string(_buffer.data(), message.header.length);

   this->start();
  }
  else {
   this->close();
  }
}
```

### Implemented message queue to write message

```
void sendResponse(const Message& response)
{
  std::string stringToSend(response.toString());

  boost::system::error_code error;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = socket().remote_endpoint(error);

  if ( error ) {
  this->close();
  }

  _strand.post(
     boost::bind(
       writeImpl,
       shared_from_this(),
       stringToSend
       )
    );
}

void writeImpl(const std::string &message)
{
  _outbox.push_back( message );
  if ( _outbox.size() > 1 ) {
    return;
  }
  this->write();
}

void write()
{
 const std::string& message = _outbox[0];
 boost::asio::async_write(
    _socket,
    boost::asio::buffer( message.c_str(), message.size() ),
    _strand.wrap(
      boost::bind(
        writeHandler,
        shared_from_this(),
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
        )
      )
    );
}

void writeHandler(
     const boost::system::error_code& e,
     const size_t bytesTransferred
     )
{
  _outbox.pop_front();

  if ( e ) {
  this->close();
  }
  if ( !_outbox.empty() ) {
   this->write();
 }
}
```

Comment: What boost version do you use? Is it fatal error, i.e. what happens if you call `asio::read` again? Are the system-times of the client and the server more or less synchronized?

Comment: I have defined messages in emum in between (0 to 100).
but I think memory gets corrupted and I got the message Type of 1701996897, which is not from defined messages.
In handleRead() function boost::asio::read() read this message type and then crashed.
I am not able to understand why this memory got corrupted and I got the wrong message type.

Comment: You likely have undefined behavior somewhere. There is no limitation of 100,000 messages in Asio. I suggest editing your question with a [sscce](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem or running your code under something like valgrind.

Comment: Also as [Bob mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14877341/283302) mixing synchronous and asynchronous methods in a server is very odd, stick to asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a client app?  If this is a server, then you might want to rethink the synchronous read being done in HandleRead and make everything asynchronous.  But, for a client app or a server that has few connections it is probably ok.

100,000 is a very interesting number - to people, not to computers.  It is a number that suggests that someone somewhere has set an artificial limit.  So, if your app is a client, then check the server code to make sure it is not closing the socket connection after 100,000 messages and vice-a-versa if your app is the server.  Maybe there is a hard coded array somewhere that is dimensioned to 100,000 and throwing an error when the limit is hit which has a side effect of closing the socket connection.

Whereever you test for an error condition from an ASIO operation, add some logging info when an error is detected.  At a minimum, write out some debug data to the console.  For example, in your handleRead method, right before calling the close method, add some debug logging.  In my app, I have a class that writes it out to both the console and a log file.

Comment: Yes, It is a server. Does it make problem if we mix sync and async reads?

Comment: I have defined messages in emum in between (0 to 100).
but I think memory gets corrupted and I got the message Type of 1701996897, which is not from defined messages.
In handleRead() function boost::asio::read() read this message type and then crashed.
I am not able to understand why this memory got corrupted and I got the wrong message type.

Comment: When I test this program with single client then this program works fine till around 800,000 messages and then crashes.
But when I test this with more than 15 clients then it gets crashed with in 100,000 messages.

Comment: Mixing sync and async reads would be a problem if you are using more than one thread.  If there is just one thread, then it is probably ok.

I would count each message received and each message sent.  Implement try/catch exception handling on each ASIO I/O handler and log the info to a file or the console, including the send and receive message count.  To debug your problem, try letting the program run in debug mode until it hits the message count of where it crashed and then step through the code and try to find the source of the error.

Comment: Another thought.  The crashing problem might not have even be in the socket code.  What you might try doing is removing any calls that process the messages and just log each send and receive message to a file to see if it crashes.  If it crashes at about the same point, then you know that the socket code has a problem.  But, if it does not crash, then you know that the problem has nothing to do with the socket code and is most likely in the message processing code.