# BOOST::async_wait error when sending bulk messages

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

In my application I am sending and receiving bulk of messages and behaving as a server.
In the mean while I check the session timeout of the client.
My program works fine when I don't use the `async_wait` in my application. but when I use `async_wait` then my application gets crashed after sending and receiving some 100,000 - 200,000 messages and following error comes.

```
"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::
clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >' what():  asio.ssl error"
```

whenever server receive any message from client then it calls `start()`.

```
   void Connection::start()
  {
   this->resetTimer();

   memset(_messageHeader.c_array(), 0, 8);
    boost::asio::async_read(_socket,
        boost::asio::buffer(_messageHeader, 8),
        _strand.wrap(
          boost::bind(
            &Connection::handleRead,
            shared_from_this(),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
            )
          )
        );
  }

   void Connection::handleRead(const boost::system::error_code& e,
      std::size_t bytesTransferred)
    {
     if (!e) {

      BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof(MessageHeader) == 8 );

      Message message ;
      message.header.fromString(
          std::string(_messageHeader.data(),
            sizeof(MessageHeader)
            )
          );
      uint32_t type = message.header.type;
      uint32_t length = message.header.length;

      boost::asio::async_read(_socket,
          boost::asio::buffer(_buffer, message.header.length),
          _strand.wrap(
            boost::bind(
              &Connection::messageRead,
              shared_from_this(),
              boost::asio::placeholders::error,
              boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
              type,
              length
              )
            )
          );
         }
    else {
      this->close();
    }
  }

void Connection::messageRead(const boost::system::error_code& e,
    std::size_t bytesTransferred, uint32_t type, uint32_t length)
{
  if (!e) {

    Message message;

    message.header.type = type;
    message.header.length = length;

    message.body = std::string(_buffer.data(), message.header.length);
    memset(_buffer.c_array(), 0, message.header.length);

    _timeoutCount = 0;

     this->start();
  }
  else {
    this->close();
  }
}


 void Connection::sendResponse(const Message& response)
 {
   std::string stringToSend(response.toString());

   boost::system::error_code error;
   boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = socket().remote_endpoint(error);

   if ( error ) {
     this->close();
   }

   _strand.post(
       boost::bind(
         &CclConnection::writeImpl,
         shared_from_this(),
         stringToSend
         )
       );
 }


 void Connection::writeImpl(const std::string &message)
 {
   _outbox.push_back( message );
   if ( _outbox.size() > 1 ) {
     return;
   }
   this->write();
 }

 void Connection::write()
 {
   const std::string& message = _outbox[0];
   boost::asio::async_write(
       _socket,
       boost::asio::buffer( message.c_str(), message.size() ),
       _strand.wrap(
         boost::bind(
           &Connection::writeHandler,
           shared_from_this(),
           boost::asio::placeholders::error,
           boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
           )
         )
       );
 }

 void Connection::writeHandler(
     const boost::system::error_code& e,
     const size_t bytesTransferred
     )
 {
   _outbox.pop_front();

   if ( e ) {
     this->close();
   }
   if ( !_outbox.empty() ) {
     this->write();
   }
 }

 // close connection
 void Connection::close()
 {
   boost::system::error_code ignoredCode;
   socket().shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both,
       ignoredCode);
   }

 void Connection::resetTimer()
 {
   if (Context::getSessionTimeout() > 0)
   {
     // timer of 10 seconds
     _timer.expires_from_now(10);
     _timer.async_wait(
         _strand.wrap(
           boost::bind(&Connection::handleTimeout,
             shared_from_this(),
             boost::asio::placeholders::error)
           )
         );
   }
 }


 void Connection::handleTimeout(const boost::system::error_code &e)
 {
   if (!_loggedIn)
     return;

   if (!e)
   {
     boost::system::error_code ec;
     boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = socket().remote_endpoint(ec);

     if (ec)
     {
       this->close();
       return;
     }
     else
     {
       _timeoutCount++;

       std::string ping = "ping";
       Message message(REQ_PING, ping);
       this->sendResponse(message);

       // no activity for quite some time now
       // so we just disconnect the session
       if (_timeoutCount > 30)
       {
         ERROR_1(TIMEOUT_OCCURED);
         this->close();
       }
       else
         this->start();
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I would bet you have undefined behavior somewhere. Post a [sscce](http://sscce.org) and we can help. Also this seems very similar to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14869128/283302) so you might want to clarify what is different.

Comment: also SO is not a *debug my code* web site, please indicate what you have tried.

Comment: In mu previous question. I didn't get the solutions.

Comment: In my previous question I didn't get the solution.
I tested my code to comment out sync_wait and tested with unlimited messages and my code works fine with that.

Comment: I have updated my code in my question.
Now I have given my full code.
Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `async_wait` handler is dispatching an `async_read` every time by invoking `Connection::start()`

```
 else
 {
   _timeoutCount++;

   std::string ping = "ping";
   Message message(REQ_PING, ping);
   this->sendResponse(message);

   // no activity for quite some time now
   // so we just disconnect the session
   if (_timeoutCount > 30)
   {
     ERROR_1(TIMEOUT_OCCURED);
     this->close();
   }
   else
     this->start(); // this will perform an async_read
 }
```

This is erroneous, and I doubt what you intend. Your program is [ill-formed](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html) when it invokes a subsequent `async_read` operation on a socket that already has one outstanding. Rather than invoking `Connection::start()` I suggest resetting the timer from within the `async_wait` handler and invoking `async_wait` again.